# Convert symbol to a list of symbols

Tags: kdb

I read in a csv file:

```
csvFile:1!("SSS"; enlist ",") 0: hsym `$"\\\\location\\of\\csv";
```

But lists of symbols are read as single symbols. e.g. in the csv file I have `'a'b'c` but

```
csvFile`some_keyed_value
`col1`col2!``a`b`c`
```

What I want is this - and note how a single ticker should be an empty list:

```
`col1`col2!(`a`b`c;())
```

Is there a way to make this cast or read in the csv differently or modify the csv so that it reads in correctly? Any modifications I make to the csv (e.g. replacing `'` with `()` ) simply converts it to a single symbol (e.g. I get `'()` ).

Here is a screenshot of a few lines from the csv

[image]

Comment: Can you add an example of your CSV file? It's not very clear exactly what is in this file. A few lines should be fine

Comment: Absolutely, I've added a screenshot of a few lines. Let me know if you need anything else. Column A is the key in case that is important to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking this csv as an example:

```
cat ex.csv
x,y
`aa`bb,
`cc`dd,`ee`ff
,`gg`hh
```

You need to load those nested symbol columns in as strings first:

```
q)show tab:("**";enlist",")0:`:ex.csv
x        y
-----------------
"`aa`bb" ""
"`cc`dd" "`ee`ff"
""       "`gg`hh"
```

From here you then need to drop the backticks and convert the strings to symbols. One possible way to do this is:

```
q)update {`$1_'where["`"=x]cut x}'[x] from tab
x          y
-------------------
`aa`bb     ""
`cc`dd     "`ee`ff"
`symbol$() "`gg`hh"
```

Comment: tab is as expected but the next update line gives me:

An error occurred during execution of the query.
The server sent the response:
x

Comment: Are you passing `x` or your column names to the lambda?

Comment: Ah yes, misread your lambda. It works identically to user2242865's one

Comment: Switched to using this one due to problem with user2242865's one noted in comments. Many thanx.

Answer (score 5):

For your input, the following works. You can also use cut instead of vs, as in previous example.

```
q)update `$table, `$_[1;]each vs["`";]each writeAllow, `$_[1;]each 
vs["`";]each writeLog from ("***";enlist",")0:`:tmp.csv

table       writeAllow            writeLog
------------------------------------------------------
:/loader/P1 `pg`sec-fg-id         `symbol$()
:/loader/P2 `pg`shara`mcdonald    `pg`MD`svc
:/loader/P3 `symbol$()            `pg`MD`svc
```

You should probably reconsider storing the sym data with backticks - it would be straightforward to store with a different delimiter to separate the sub-records and have a dedicated function for parsing those fields.

Comment: Perfect thanx, ultimately used this simply because it is one line less but Thomas's cut answer works identically as you say.

Comment: Actually Problem: the keyed value does not always have a leading ":" but  this loads in keyed values without the leading : and adds a leading :

Comment: The issue here is you are trying to manipulate data structures that kdb+ has special representation for, but kdb+ doesn't save them in the format you're trying to read.  The strings with leading ":" are representations of a filepath (http://code.kx.com/q/ref/datatypes/#filepaths) and the syms are written with leading "`". I wouldnt recommend storing either in the csv representation - they only make sense within kdb+.

Comment: You could also just remove `hsym` from the above line of code.

Comment: Fair point - assumed that they would be used as filepaths...  Changed.

Answer (score 3):

You can also utilize the function `value` to convert a string with embedded backticks to a symbol list.

```
// read in as strings as others have said
q)("**";1#",")0:`:test.csv
x      y
-------------
"`a`b" "`c`d"
"`e`f" "`g`f"
// value each string to convert to symbol lists
q)value@''("**";1#",")0:`:test.csv
x   y
-------
a b c d
e f g f
// check its now nested symbol type
q)meta value@''("**";1#",")0:`:test.csv
c| t f a
-| -----
x| S
y| S
```

You can of course use `value` on specific columns that you need if it serves your purposes too, ie `update value each col1 from ...`

Comment: This doesn't work with symbols with special characters like "`sec-fg-id"

Comment: indeed - only run it on feasible columns, say writeLog in the actual example given by the op. my sample data was maybe too simple

Answer (score 2):

```
q)t
table      writeAllow               writeLog
----------------------------------------------------------
:loader/p1 "`pg`sec-fg-id"       ""
:loader/p2 "`pg`shara`cmacdonald" "`pg`MD`svc"
:loader/p3 ""                       "`pg`MD`svc"    

q)foo:(`$1_"`" vs) each
q)update foo[writeAllow], foo[writeLog] from t
table      writeAllow             writeLog
------------------------------------------------------
:loader/p1 `pg`sec-fg-id       `symbol$()
:loader/p2 `pg`shara`mcdonald `pg`MD`svc
:loader/p3 `symbol$()             `pg`MD`svc
```